# How do you update a mongoDB document by inserting a field as an object?

Tags: mongodb

My goal is to insert a field in my database as an object using shell as below.

```
reviewers: Object
  reviewer1: "Alpha"
  reviewer2: "Beta"
  reviewer3: "Gamma"
```

I've tried several queries such as the following, but it entered the field as an array of object

```
db.movieDetails.update({"title": "The Martian"}, {$push:{"reviewers":{$each:[{"reviewer1":"Alpha"},{"reviewer2":"Beta"},{"reviewer3":"Gamma"}]}}})
```

What query would do exactly what I'm looking for?

Your input will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to append the object to an existing one without remove the old fields you can use dot notation in this way:

```js
db.collection.update({
  "title": "The Martian"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "reviewers.reviewer1": "Alpha",
    "reviewers.reviewer2": "Beta",
    "reviewers.reviewer3": "Gamma"
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/gg0NJN2uHxV)

But if you only want to set the entire object, then use `$set` with the object you want to insert into `reviewers`.

```js
db.collection.update({
  "title": "The Martian"
},
{
  "$set": {
    "reviewers": {
      "reviewer1": "Alpha",
      "reviewer2": "Beta",
      "reviewer3": "Gamma"
    }
  }
})
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rZzpfWH93la)

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
db.movieDetails.update({"title": "The Martian"}, {"reviewers":{"reviewer1":"Alpha","reviewer2":"Beta","reviewer3":"Gamma"}})
```

Edit: This will replace the entire document.

Comment: no `$set` needed?

Comment: @Visrozar thank you for your help. But when I tried, it replaced the whole document instead of inserting the field.

Comment: @ITselect if you only want to add/edit fields to an existing document, then you should use "$set", without it, it'll replace the entire document. 

My bad for not understanding the question clearly. I think J.F. has written a better explanation.

Comment: @Minsky You're right. I added $set and it did exactly the work. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
db.regexPractice.update({"Employee id": 22}, {$set:{"reviewers":{"reviewer1":"Alpha","reviewer2":"Beta","reviewer3":"Gamma"}}}
```

And it worked correctly.